# How do i pass two or more parameters to two different tables using Joins on Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, parameters

i have the exams table, the subjects table, and the exam_subjects table. i want to filter lets say by Exam.id and Subject.id on the WHERE how do i pass those parameters.

```
@exams = Exam.joins(exam_subjects: :subject).where(:exam_id => params[:exam_id], :subject_id => params[:subject_id])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like

```
@exams = Exam.joins(exam_subjects: :subject).where(:id => [params[:exam_id], params[:subject_id]])
```

?

Comment: You'll need to specify the table name whenever you use the "id" field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an string as a parameter in the where condition:

```
@exams = Exam.joins(exam_subjects: :subject).where('id = ? AND exam_id = ?', params[:exam_id], params[:subject_id])
```

Take a look at  [Pure String Conditions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pure-string-conditions) on active record.